# How can I plot predicted vs. actual values for a regression tree in R?

Tags: r, plot, random-forest, decision-tree

I am new to R. Since I've done a regression tree and a prediction based on my test data, I wanted to plot the actual vs. predicted values. Which function would you recommend for this? Also, is there a function for the same issue for a random forest?

I tried the basic function "plot", but then I ended up with the regression tree on the y axis and the actual value on the x axis, which was not my intention.

Comment: You can use the `ggplot2` package for plotting. Without a reproducible sample, I cannot help you much further than this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the ggplot package rather than the default plot function. Store the actual value and the predicted value in a dataframe and plot it using the ggplot package.

```
actualAndPredictedData = data.frame(actualValue = testData$y, 
                                    predictedValue = predict(rTreeModel,testData))

ggplot(actualAndPredictedData,aes(x = actualValue, y = predictedValue) +
geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you! And is it possible to rename the ylab and xlab in this function?